# Why does one PHP Code work while as the other doesn't?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The following php code creates the database but doesn't create tables.

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
     $sql = "CREATE DATABASE Stackoverflow;";
     $res = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
     mysqli_close($db);
define('DB_DATABASE', 'Stackoverflow');
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
     $sql = file_get_contents("data.sql"); 
     $res = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
```

This php file creates the tables.

```
$db = 'Stackoverflow';
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'password';
    $connection = new PDO(
    "mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$db, $user, $pass,
    [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC]
);
    $sql = file_get_contents("data.sql");
    $connection->exec($sql);
```

These are the contents of my data.sql file:

```
    CREATE TABLE Booking_tbl (
    BookingId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ClassId int NOT NULL,
    UserName varchar(140),
    PRIMARY KEY(BookingId)
);

CREATE TABLE Class_tbl (
              ClassId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    TeacherId int NOT NULL,
    ClassName varchar(140) NOT NULL,
   TimeSlot int NOT NULL,
    SemesterId int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ClassId)
);

CREATE TABLE Teacher_tbl (
    TeacherId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    TeacherName varchar(140) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(TeacherId)
);

CREATE TABLE Semester_tbl (
    SemesterId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    SemesterName varchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (SemesterId)
);
```

When I run the first file, it correctly creates the database, but it will not create the tables I want it to create in the database. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Did you confirm that the connection to the database is done properly? And does the manual import of the sql file works?

Comment: Did you select the database where you want your table to be created? use my_new_db;

Comment: @MdMonjurUlHasan the connection to the database, I am not sure, but the connection to server is done properly.

Comment: @JeffreyHitosis How would you use my_new_db?

Comment: I was just saying that you set your default database to your database using the command "use your_database;" to switch to your database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass the contents of 'data.sql', you are passing multiple queries to `mysqli_query` which (I believe) is not allowed. Try using `mysqli_multi_query` instead.

Comment: The following is the error I ge when I try to do that

Comment: mysqli_multi_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given

Comment: Why are you passing a boolean? You were passing a `mysqli` before, what are you doing differently now? I guess I need to see your updated code.

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand the actual problem. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Once you create the database, then you need to select the database. You are missing this step.

```
mysqli_select_db($con,"test");
```

Comment: Would I do $db=mysqli_select_db($con, test); then do mysqli_query($db,$sql);?